# Windows 10 connection to wifi keeps failing

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, usb

I just installed a fresh copy of Windows 10. I wish I listened to people who advised against it.

The largest issue with the OS is that after about a minute, the connection to WiFi stops working. The system does not indicate disconnect, but I cannot even connect to the router's IP, so the connection is clearly down. Disconnecting and reconnecting fixes this, but only for another 60 seconds.

There are three other devices connected to the network with no problems - I'm using another notebook to post this question.

The Windows 10 is installed on desktop PC, so I use USB WiFi dongle to connect to WiFi. I have two of them, from different manufacturers (TP-Link and some unknown brand). Both of them work on Windows 7 and Ubuntu with no problems. Both of them suffer from the same problem on Windows 10.

Each dongle uses different driver. I did ask windows to update drivers for both. Windows claims that they are up to date. I also have made sure that Windows Update is downloaded and installed.

Windows shows no errors. Is this a known issue? I have exhausted all options that are applicable when this problem occurs on OS written by sober people.

Technical info:

Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 1809
OS build: 17763.253
Dongle driver: Realtek RTL8192CU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter

Comment: Note that I understand that the question might lack important details, but I'm new to Win10, so I do not know what details are important and where to find them. Please ask in comments and I will improve the question.